# Methods to set width or height on a dynamically-sized element using only CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Aside from using flexbox, what are some ways to set a height within a container where a sibling changes its size dynamically? Using only CSS.

The reason why I ask is that I have to support some very old browsers.

Example:

```
<div class="widget">
    <div class="nav">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
</div>
```

I don't know the size of the widget as clients can change the dimensions as they wish. The nav element is also customizable. The catch is that I want to provide scrolling when content reaches past the rest of the space.

Comment: `display: table`, `display: table-cell` comes to mind. Can you post your code illustrating the problem?

Comment: @fubar Just did, hope that helps

Comment: Please include CSS.

Comment: So are you trying to make the two elements within `.widget` have the same height, when one changes dynamically?

Comment: @fubar Say the widget has a height of 800px, and nav 50px. In this case, I'd like the content to have a height of 750 so it scrolls within the extra space. However, both the height and nav could change, so I need to take that into account for the height of the content.

Comment: Ah right, okay. I didn't understand that from your question. And to confirm, the height of the `nav` element isn't fixed?

Comment: It too can be dynamic. Previously, I had everything set as flex and the navbar would have a flex-shrink of 0, so people can change the height as they wish. The content with flex-grow of 1 which allowed me to never work with static values. But I need to support older browsers unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you can modify your HTML structure to add two container `<div>` elements. Doing so will allow you to utilise the `display: table`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` CSS properties.

By setting a small height value on the `.nav` cell, it'll automatically expand to whatever size is required by it's content. And by not setting a height on the `.content` cell, it'll fill the remaining space.

Finally, using an inner `<div>` with `max-height: 100%` and `overflow-y: scroll`, you can force the content to scroll when it's too large for the available space.

```css
.widget {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: table;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-container,
.content-container {
  display: table-row;
}

.nav {
  background-color: blue;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 1px;  // Set a very small height value, and it'll expand automatically
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  display: table-cell;
}

.scroll {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="nav">
      One<br>Two<br>Three
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="scroll">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pro id volumus efficiendi delicatissimi, cu nullam accommodare mei. At lobortis abhorreant ius. Qui soleat albucius tractatos eu, sed dolorum nonumes scribentur ne, ex mazim feugiat theophrastus has. No vix omnis congue. Et mea volumus postulant, ne qui veritus complectitur.</p>
      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pro id volumus efficiendi delicatissimi, cu nullam accommodare mei. At lobortis abhorreant ius. Qui soleat albucius tractatos eu, sed dolorum nonumes scribentur ne, ex mazim feugiat theophrastus has. No vix omnis congue. Et mea volumus postulant, ne qui veritus complectitur.</p>
      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pro id volumus efficiendi delicatissimi, cu nullam accommodare mei. At lobortis abhorreant ius. Qui soleat albucius tractatos eu, sed dolorum nonumes scribentur ne, ex mazim feugiat theophrastus has. No vix omnis congue. Et mea volumus postulant, ne qui veritus complectitur.</p>
      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pro id volumus efficiendi delicatissimi, cu nullam accommodare mei. At lobortis abhorreant ius. Qui soleat albucius tractatos eu, sed dolorum nonumes scribentur ne, ex mazim feugiat theophrastus has. No vix omnis congue. Et mea volumus postulant, ne qui veritus complectitur.</p>
      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pro id volumus efficiendi delicatissimi, cu nullam accommodare mei. At lobortis abhorreant ius. Qui soleat albucius tractatos eu, sed dolorum nonumes scribentur ne, ex mazim feugiat theophrastus has. No vix omnis congue. Et mea volumus postulant, ne qui veritus complectitur.</p>
      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pro id volumus efficiendi delicatissimi, cu nullam accommodare mei. At lobortis abhorreant ius. Qui soleat albucius tractatos eu, sed dolorum nonumes scribentur ne, ex mazim feugiat theophrastus has. No vix omnis congue. Et mea volumus postulant, ne qui veritus complectitur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you keep a resource for these things, or is it like straight from your head? I need to know...

Comment: I made that up for this answer, but it's just leveraging the behaviour of HTML tables. It may well be a documented solution somewhere though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media rule to apply different styles for different media types/devices in terms of screen height and width.
For example you can set an element style based on screen width:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
     }
}
```

You can even add a css stylesheet based on what size of screen the user is using.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 900px)" href="widescreen.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="smallscreen.css">
```

You can check more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).